# A generalized norm function in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, metric-spaces

We defined a new norm. The norm of $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is defined as
$$ N_P(x) = \min \{t \geq 0 : x \in t\cdot P\} \enspace,$$
where $P$ is a centrally symmetric and convex body centered at the origin point.

We prove that it is a norm.

1.Identity of indiscernibles.
Obviously, $N_P(x)=0 \Leftrightarrow x=0$.

2.Absolutely scalable.

Because of centrally symmetric property, $N_P(ax)=|a|N_P(x)$.

3.Triangle inequality.

Denote $N_P(x+y), N_P(x),N_P(y)$ as $t_0,t_1,t_2$ respectively. And let vectors $x+y,x,y$ go from the origin point and hit the border of $P$ at $a,b,c$ respectively.

Therefore $(x+y)=x+y$ implies $t_0\vec{a}=t_1\vec{b}+t_2\vec{c}$, implies $\vec{a}=\frac{t_1}{t_0}\vec{b}+\frac{t_2}{t_0}\vec{c}$

Suppose $t_0 > t_1+t_2$, thus $0\leq \frac{t_1}{t_0}+\frac{t_2}{t_0}<1$.

However, this contradict to the convex property because border $bac$ is not convex. QED

We realized this new norm consists all possible norms in $\mathbb{R}^n$, including $\ell_p$.

Because for any norm $N(\cdot)$, define $P=\{ x : N(x)\leq 1\}$, one can verify that $N_P=N$. It shows a simple fact: a norm is equivalent to the space which has unit norm.

Our question is, did anyone discover it before? What is the name? We googled it but did not get answers.

By the way, if no one named it, we'd like to name it as polymorphic norm.

Comment: could you show a counterexample? @Nikio

Comment: my bad, I was wrong!

Comment: This reminds me of polyhedral norms, maybe this is a related concept?

Comment: Searching for 'convex is unit ball of norm' gives more or less your construction as the first result https://www-ljk.imag.fr//membres/Anatoli.Iouditski/cours/convex/chapitre_3.pdf p.9 (it uses the convex set to make a norm on the dual but it is similar)